# apt -o APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages=true install <pkg> does not keep debs in docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, apt

I'm running an ubuntu:16.04 on docker (`Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d`):

```
docker run -it ubuntu:16.04
```

and inside I'm running `apt -o APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages=true install curl`

which should install curl, and not remove the debs from `/var/cache/apt/archives`, but this does not happen. The package is installed but the deb is not saved in the cache (or rather, saved and then deleted).

I tried it on my host:

```
lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:printing-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:printing-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

and there it worked as expected (i.e. package was saved).

Checked the apt version in both the container and the host. Both run the same apt - `apt 1.2.32 (amd64)`

What can differ between the host and the container that would be the cause of ignoring the `APT option`?

Comment: See `/etc/apt/apt.conf/docker-clean` in the stock `ubuntu` image.  In typical Docker-oriented use there will be only one or maybe two calls to `apt-get install` in a Dockerfile and it will never get called after that, so there's no use in keeping the `.deb` files around and they get automatically cleaned up.

Comment: Cool! I checked my `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean` and found this `DPkg::Post-Invoke { "rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true"; };
APT::Update::Post-Invoke { "rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true"; };
`. I guess that deleting both lines would solve my problems, even without calling the APT option

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @David Maze for the comment that led me here.

The difference was this. The docker container I installed, had a configuration file inside `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` called `docker-clean` which held 3 lines:

```
DPkg::Post-Invoke { "rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true"; };                                                          │
APT::Update::Post-Invoke { "rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true"; };                                                   │
Dir::Cache::pkgcache ""; Dir::Cache::srcpkgcache "";
```

This options seem to have overridden my `APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages=true`. However, after removing the first 2 lines, and reusing the `APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages=true` the debs were kept in the archives dir